# onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory when using admob with adwhirl

Tags: android, admob, adwhirl

i just want to know if this problem is server side...or i must fix something in my code...

onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory

I'm using admob with adwhirl to show ads in my android application.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are getting this error, then your code is correct.  The issue is that AdMob does not always have an ad to return for every request.  This may happen particularly if you have just registered your AdMob publisher ID, as it takes some time and multiple requests before the new ID starts returning ads.

Another reason your fill rate may be low is that you don't have AdSense backfill enabled, or you have filtered out some ads.  Check your app settings to see if that is the case.

Finally, a test you can run to see if your AdWhirl code is implemented correctly is to request a test ad.  You can do this by specifying test mode in AdWhirl:

```
AdWhirlTargeting.setTestMode(true);
```

If you get back a test ad, you'll know your code is working as intended.

Comment: Thanks alot Eric....i tried the last line and it worked...so every thing is OK...but i already filtered some ads..so maybe this is the reason..
Can i add filter to AdSense??

Comment: Unfortunately, AdSense is just an on/off switch, so you can't really control what ads come from there.  I think they are more strict about what ads they show, however, so you shouldn't have to worry about setting filters on the AdSense ads.

Comment: Hi eric, i have tested my code with addTestDevice("CF95DC53F383F9A836FD749F3EF439CD"); and the google ad was displayed. but when i use my live adunit id. getting the above error, the ad is not loading. Is it  because of any filtering mode? Can i show the ad with admob only? should i need to use Adwhirl?

Answer (score 6):

One of the solutions you could try:

Some times this will happened if you changed language of your Android device to exotic language (Russian for example). Try to change it back to English and AdMob will find appropriate ad for you. Or you could go to the **Google Settings->Ads->Reset advertising ID**

Comment: Google Settings->Ads->Reset advertising ID works. Is it there any other solution from android code? without change that setting

Answer (score 2):

I've just found that such error is shown if your AdMob account has been **banned**. But it works with a test device ID.

Comment: Why these minuses? This answer is totally valid, maybe for very few people, but it is 100% TRUE! And you could spend a lot of time debugging just to find out that Google decided to ban you account for only God knows why!

Answer (score 0):

Note that this might happen aswell if you're using (forcing) a custom width and height for the banners.

You should use the ones that DOC states:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#play

If you set a custom width and height like:

```
new AdSize( 521,300 );
```

It's going to reply with the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was from long time ago, but here's something i did which solved this problem.
1. on your **admob** account, click on "manage settings" in the app you've created.
2. click on "edit".
3. under "Android Package URL:" leave blank, and then save settings.

*after you'll save, it'll show this box as "market://", which is fine.

Comment: can you please send screenshots or link for this steps?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using **Rewarded Interstitial (beta)**.
Changing to **Rewarded** solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an issue with capitalisation, when you ad your app in AdMob be sure to match the packagename of the app deployed in the play store.

Configuration #1 won't show ads ever (even no test ads), while conf. #2 started showing ads immediately

```
 #  Play store      AdMob   AdMob package
--  --------------  ------  --------------
 1  org.sde.rdmaps  rdMaps  org.sde.rdmaps
 2  org.sde.rdMaps  rdMaps  org.sde.rdmaps
```

Note the capital M in the second "org.sde.rd**M**aps"