# android Admob stopped coming suddenly

Tags: android, admob

I have an application in which AD was successfully running. I was using **test AD id** from google. Ad was coming properly. Now Ads stopped coming.

It says **request successful, onfailed to receive Ad because lack of ad inventory.**

I read same on stack overflow questions and saw many answers. But am wondered why Ads  stopped suddenly!!

I had several code changes in between. **But when I tried with one of my older version apk, then also Ad is not coming.**

Now my application is complete. So am going to Add **original Ad Id**. So will there be any problems? And what  this case means? This is something server side right?
How can I get other Test Ad Ids from google? Or is there any way to test for ads?

one simple question too.. Once I integrated my original Ad Id can I install it in my device before uploading to google play? Am new too all these. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that's the same issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778756/onfailedtoreceiveadad-request-successful-but-no-ad-returned-due-to-lack-of-ad

Comment: dont know much on Adwhirl. Also I was testing with test Ad Id from google.

Comment: From the linked question's answer: _The issue is that AdMob does not always have an ad to return for every request._

Comment: from last two days no Ads coming. Will it happen sometimes? Am new to this. Thanks

Comment: I'm not using admob (or any ad provider), so I have no idea. However, your issue seems to be quite common; recommendations are to display ads from another ad provider or own images instead, for example http://jmsliu.com/828/how-to-add-admob-interstitial-ads-in-your-android-apps.html

Comment: Thank you:) I will read that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From time to time most ad networks will have no ad to display. THis is the difference between an AdRequest (you asked for an ad) and an AdImpression (you received an ad).

TO counter that it is common to use Ad mediation and configure several networks such that if one fails to deliver an ad then next network is asked to provide one.

Personally I use Admob to mediate and include about 3 other networks to deliver alternate ad fill. NB mediation is also useful for keeping you eCPM rate high or switching off ad networks that start behaving aberrantly.

Comment: me also using AdMob. Admob itself mediating three networks? or do i have to set something for this? Thanks @William

Comment: so if I add my original AdId and try, I hope it will work. Is it so? @william

Comment: You configure your Admob AdView with the ID from the Admob console (Something like "ca-****-****"). And then in the console for that ad property you configure the ids for the networks that you want to include in your mediation flow. Don't forget to include the libraries for those networks and the mediation adapters for each too.  See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation#android