# Why isn't my app showing AdMob ads?

Tags: android, admob

I have this Android application that has ads but they are not showing.
In my LogCat it says:

`onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory)`

Does anyone have an idea why aren't they showing? thanks

Comment: Have you tried just googling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778756/onfailedtoreceiveadad-request-successful-but-no-ad-returned-due-to-lack-of-ad

Answer (score 2):

> The issue is that AdMob does not always have an ad to return for every
>   request. This may happen particularly if you have just registered your
>   AdMob publisher ID, as it takes some time and multiple requests before
>   the new ID starts returning ads.

For details please visit following Stack Overflow discussion:
[onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory when using admob with adwhirl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778756/onfailedtoreceiveadad-request-successful-but-no-ad-returned-due-to-lack-of-ad)