# Google admob with react-native version 0.57

Tags: android, react-native, admob, version

I tried to integrate **google admob** with **react-native 0.57** but I had some problems. 
Can someone help me writing all the steps to have a working google admob banner in react-native?

P.S. : I am developing app for android devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a great text about this
https://medium.com/@TarikHajji/add-admob-to-react-native-app-5b1e91be459

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forget to say that I develop my app for android devices, can you help me ?

Comment: Sure. You  install   react-native-admob plugin and configured with your account data ? What error appear?

Comment: Here what I've done:
1) react-native init testAd --version 0.55.2
2) npm i react-native-admob -S
3) react-native link
4) react-native run-android

ERROR: 
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-admob'.
      > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-admob:_debugPublishCopy'.
         > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:12.0.1.

Comment: Try npm install --save react-native-admob@next , react-navigation link react-native-admob

Comment: Having the same problemo :(

Comment: So... yout can try use react-native-firebase plugin to this 
1 - npm install --save react-native-firebase
2 - npm link react-native firebase

3- Create a firebase account for your app. 
4- go to firebase console, project overview add app
5- download file google-services.json 
6- put file in root_project/android/app/

Comment: 7 - edit android/build.gradle
buildscript {
  // ...
  dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
  }
}

Comment: 8 - edit app/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Dependencies {
  // This should be here already
  implementation project(':react-native-firebase')

  // Firebase dependencies
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1"

Comment: 9 - edit android/app/src/main/java/com/[app name]/MainApplication.java
import io.invertase.firebase.admob.RNFirebaseAdMobPackage; // <-- Add this line

protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new RNFirebasePackage(),
          new RNFirebaseAdMobPackage() // <-- Add this line

This is it...

Comment: usage: 
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

firebase.admob().initialize('ca-app-pub-xxx'); 
const Banner = firebase.admob.Banner;
const AdRequest = firebase.admob.AdRequest;
const request = new AdRequest();
request.addKeyword('foo');

<Banner unitId='ca-app-pub-xxx' size={"BANNER"} request={request.build()}
   onAdLoaded={() => {
      console.warn('loaded');
   }}
   onAdFailedToLoad={(error) => {
      console.warn(error.message);
   }}
/>      
reference : https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/admob/android

for me it's ok in a test app

Comment: Oh thank you! I'm going to try this now. Which react-native version do you use?

Comment: I use with react-native 0.57

Comment: I follow what you said to me and I had this error on Node: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L1QGWvwvqwhkKRV2eI-AuWzroIDjLNBS.          On my other react-native apps the error does not exists and everything work well.

Comment: Here I upload pics about both Node error and my C:/ folders. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1d3TaU73OcO4zm71IXs5k46QOVSPAgcCK.       Tahnk you for your help! :)

Comment: Try npm start -- --reset-cache

Comment: Same problem :(     https://drive.google.com/open?id=1d3TaU73OcO4zm71IXs5k46QOVSPAgcCK

Comment: I solved this error and now I get this "import" error in the last photo of my drive directory ('Cattura4') :   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1d3TaU73OcO4zm71IXs5k46QOVSPAgcCK

Comment: the error say that you have two or more firebase import.

Comment: I wrote import firebase only once, how can I do?

Comment: please, copy all content of your file .

Comment: All files except node_modules folder?

Comment: Ok I solved the problem, now with an example API (ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111) the app show the banner perfectlybut with my API I get this error:        "The ad request was successful, no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory".           Can you list me how get an API of Ad Mob and link it to frebase step by step??

Comment: it's good. The code is correct. 
the error is in your ads. In some cases is need wait some hours or days to campaing start.
The point is, if it's ok with the exemple code, it's all ok!.

Comment: I have the same problem after 3 days, where can I find this two 'KEYS' ??     firebase.admob().initialize('KEY 1');    and      <Banner 
   unitId='KEY 2' 
   size={"BANNER"} 
   request={request.build()} 
   onAdLoaded={() => { console.warn('loaded'); }} 
   onAdFailedToLoad={(error) => { console.warn(error.message); }} 
   />           can you post me some screen about it ??  Do I have to register a credit card to let API KEY works ?

Comment: Can you Sergio help me ?? I create my banner and get its ID 5/6 days ago,  but nothing changes...

Comment: Hey, sorry, but i don't have any idea what can be the problem. Maybe your ad in admob is incorrect.  I search in web and don't found any good answer for this. Only what i just say.... Se see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778756/onfailedtoreceiveadad-request-successful-but-no-ad-returned-due-to-lack-of-ad 

It maybe help u.