# Can't run my react-native app because I'm having an error

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, admob

I installed react-native-firebase and follow any of the steps of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53297730/google-admob-with-react-native-version-0-57/53299688?noredirect=1#comment93600858_53299688),
but I have [this problem](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1d3TaU73OcO4zm71IXs5k46QOVSPAgcCK) on Node and I don't know how to solve it. Can someone help me ??

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because I dont have enough reputation, so I'll post this here.

Try to delete the node_modules from the project and run 'npm install'. It will recreate the node_modules folder, see if this will fix the issue