# Admob updated, not showing ads unless anymore unless testing?

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I have an app that has had Admob integrated for years (so it's not a new ad spot).

I just updated Admob to latest "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.1" from a previous verison, maybe 15 or 16 something. And consistently I am now getting this in logcat

> Failed to load ad: 3 (No Fill)
>
> No fill from any mediation ad networks.

**1. If I add my device as a test device, I do get the test ad**

**2. If I download my app from the Play Store and try, I see ads are working (using the exact same interstitial/admob ID) so account is working...**

I know I'm supposed to use test ads when in testing environment, but I'd like to see a live ad before pushing out an app update you know? Did Firebase change something to detect if it's not a "live" app?

(No code because it is the typical admob loading code which has been untouched, and as I said, test ads work)

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL) you are getting the following error code:

> **public static final int ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL**
>
> The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of
>   ad inventory.
>
> Constant Value: 3

Based on the post 
[onFailedToReceiveAd - Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory when using admob with adwhirl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778756/onfailedtoreceiveadad-request-successful-but-no-ad-returned-due-to-lack-of-ad):

> If you are getting this error, then your code is correct. The issue is
>   that AdMob does not always have an ad to return for every request.
>   This may happen particularly if you have just registered your AdMob
>   publisher ID, as it takes some time and multiple requests before the
>   new ID starts returning ads.
>
> Another reason your fill rate may be low is that you don't have
>   AdSense backfill enabled, or you have filtered out some ads. Check
>   your app settings to see if that is the case.

Maybe you must try launch your app with other ip to get new ads.

Comment: thanks, yeah I saw that too, what's putting me off is if I immediately just download the production version of the same app, using the same admob credentials, there *is* filled ads

just worried this "error code 3" will continue after pushing this update, but will just have to release and see I suppose

Comment: its normal that you get error code 3. Because of each person can see specified number of ads. when you see each time ads, admob dont show again afs to you and send error code 3. I saw this error much when i develop app. but trust me. its normal :)