# Integrating Mopub with AdMob mediation

Tags: flutter, admob, mopub, mobile-ad-mediation

I am trying to show MoPub ads through mediation with AdMob. and i did everything on the tutorial

but the ads not showing this what i got :

W/MoPubAdapter(26392): 3: No ads found.
W/flutter (26392): onAdFailedToLoad: 3
I/Ads     (26392): Ad failed to load : 3
I/flutter (26392): InterstitialAd event MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad

pls help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is most likely correct, code 3 just means that there are no ads being served from Admob.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778756/onfailedtoreceiveadad-request-successful-but-no-ad-returned-due-to-lack-of-ad)

> If you are getting this error, then your code is correct. The issue is that AdMob does not always have an ad to return for every request. This may happen particularly if you have just registered your AdMob publisher ID, as it takes some time and multiple requests before the new ID starts returning ads.
> Another reason your fill rate may be low is that you don't have AdSense backfill enabled, or you have filtered out some ads. Check your app settings to see if that is the case.